# Erlang receive after

Tags: parallel-processing, erlang, timeout, wait

I am having issues making my receive after function work in Erlang, I've googled and banged my head against this for some time now but can't seem to figure it out and would need some help. I have a process which runs the following process and waits for messages.

```
% Waits for messages, and puts them into the list. 
% If the list has the same length as the Length variable 
% which is the original provided list, then it means we are done
% and can print the results.
% If the MaxTime has passed it should just print the provided list.
wait_max_time(List, Length, MaxTime) ->
io:format("I am ~p and waiting...~n", [self()]),
receive
    X -> 
        Results = List ++ [X],
        case length(Results) =:= Length of
            true -> 
                io:format("~p~n", [Results]),
                exit(self());
            false -> 
                wait(Results, Length)
        end
after MaxTime -> io:format("List is ~p~n", [List])
end.
```

Everything above the after seems to work fine, it always computes and I've confirmed it with print statements.

But for calculations which takes too long time, I simply want to print the list it got and not continue. But after never gets runned in my code, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean to call `wait_max_time` and not `wait` in `false -> ...`?

Comment: Side issue: the #1 rule in [List Handling](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html) is that you never append to the end of a list. It can be okay for very short lists, but you should just get into the habit of build lists like `[X | List]` instead of `List ++ [X]`.

Comment: The code you gave doesn't really demonstrate the problem. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would go a long way toward getting you a good answer. It may be that you're slow-DoS-ing yourself by trickling messages to this process. Note that the `after` timeout resets every time a message is received.

Answer (score 0):

As Dogbert pointed out in the comment, I completely missed that I forgot to change a name of a function under false which called another function which didn't have the timeout.

Problem is solved, thanks.